# Apache log to database

Tags: apache, logging

I'm in the middle of setting up various web servers for my company that hosts several websites.  Some of the sites could be hosted on any server at any point in time (floating IPs).

For ease of use, I'd like to send all the Apache log information to a database.  I have experience using cronolog for rotating logs on a daily basis, but I'd like to update the database more often than that.  It seems as though cronolog or just straight Apache, both stream to the log file (probably for performance reasons).  If I were to move the file for database processing, they continue writing to said file.

Has anyone done this and have any advice for setting something like this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into using logtail and grab what you need.